# How can i perform routing with multiple Ids in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, url-routing

**How can i perform routing with below URLs**

I have following types of URLs

1. `api/country` It will return all country
2. `api/country/1` It will return specific country
3. `api/country/1/state` it will return all state of country 1
4. `api/country/1/state/1` it will return specific state of specific country
5. `api/country/1/state/1/city` it will return all city of state 1 country 1
6. `api/country/1/state/1/city/1` it will return specific city of state 1 country 1

Comment: this seems like a straightforward and common use case. If you are stuck somewhere, can you show the code you tried? if you are researching, have you tried checking any documentation?

Comment: I have tried with this way -  [Route("country/{id}/state/{id}/city/{id}")] but its not working. It through error like - The route parameter name 'id' appears more than one time in the route template.

I am looking for best way to route my endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route parameter does not have to say "id". You can pick any variable name. For instance:

```
[HttpGet("api/country/{countryId}/state/{stateId}/city/{cityId")]
public IActionResult GetCity(
        [FromRoute]int countryId, [FromRoute]int stateId, [FromRoute]int cityId)
{
    // pick what you want to return here
}
```

If you use the `[ApiController]` on your controller class, you wouldn't have to use `[FromRoute]` on every attribute.